# How to sign XML with line breaks and indentation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, digital-signature, xml-signature, java-security

I have problems with the signature of a  formated XML.  when I do the serialization of the object, I specify the indentantion. The result XML Contains indentation and line breaks. Later, i sign the XML, but at the moment of deserialize the Document object, again i apply indentantion to the result String (is this correct ?). The validation of the result XML signature fails. This does not happen when I process the xml without applying any formatting. For this case, the signature  validation is successful.

Yes, the solution would be to sign the XML without formatting it. But this is not a solution for my case.

Can help me, please.  Here is my code:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);


    DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
            myXmlString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    Document doc = builder.parse(stream);


   KeyStore ks = getKeyStore();
    PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(my_key_alias,
            new String(mykey_password).toCharArray());
    Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate(my_certificate_alias);
    PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();

    DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(privateKey,
            doc.getDocumentElement());
    dsc.putNamespacePrefix("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", "ds");
    dsc.setDefaultNamespacePrefix("ds");

    XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
    Reference ref = fac.newReference("", fac.newDigestMethod(
            DigestMethod.SHA1, null), Collections.singletonList(fac
            .newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED,
                    (TransformParameterSpec) null)), null, null);

    SignedInfo si = fac
            .newSignedInfo(fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(
                    CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE_WITH_COMMENTS,
                    (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null), fac
                    .newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1, null),
                    Collections.singletonList(ref));

    KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks
            .getEntry(my_key_aliass, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(
                    my_key_password.toCharArray()));

    X509Certificate certX509 = (X509Certificate)       keyEntry.getCertificate();
    List x509Content = new ArrayList();
    x509Content.add(certX509.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
    x509Content.add(certX509);
    X509Data xd = kif.newX509Data(x509Content);
    KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(xd));

    XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);

    signature.sign(dsc);
```

The deserialization of the object

```
    OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(doc);

    format.setLineWidth(200);
    format.setIndent(4);

    StringWriter stringOut = new StringWriter();

    XMLSerializer serial = new XMLSerializer(stringOut, format);

    serial.serialize(doc);

    //XML WITH THE SIGNATURE
    return stringOut.toString();
```

Where can I specify that the XML to be signed has indentation and line breaks?

I use XMLSerializer  because I had a versioning problem when trying to use Transform  with XERCES 2.4.0. I can not update the xerces API.

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you serialize the XML **before** signing?

Comment: Did you finally make this work????

Comment: No, in the end it was not necessary to sign it with line breaks, I hope you succeed in your attempt.